# How goddess Parvati had started her penance?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, parvati

I want to know about her tough penance. What did her routine during that period ? How she had worshipped Lord Shiva as per Shiva Purana? Did Lord Shiva had appeared as a brahmin & insulted himself in front of parvati? Overall what was the scenario? Please tell me ( if possible, then please provide shlokas in Devanagari from Shiva Purana).

Answer (score 0):

According to Shiva Purana,

1) Parvati performed rigorous penance.  The full narrative can be found from [**Sl.no.29 to 60**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226086.html) of Chapter 22 - Description of Pārvatī’s penance in Shiva Purana.

2) Shiva did appear as brahmin and tried to dissuade Parvati by narrating himself in a negative manner.  The full narrative can be found from [**Sl.nO.12 to 38**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226091.html) of Chapter 27 - Description of the fraudulent words of the Brahmacārin of Shiva Purana.

3) The overall scenario after Shiva's consenting to marry Parvati was happy.